# about parabolic cone

Tags: alexandrov-geometry, dg.differential-geometry

I want to prove some Alexandrov space M is parabolic cone X x R.Since Alex has no Riemannian metric,so how to do?Is there any (triangle) formula about the relation of distance of two points in M and distance of the projection points in X?

Answer (score 1):

The metric  of warp products $F\times_f B$ is fiber independent.
It means that if $(x,a),(y,b)\in F\times_f B$ and $(x',a),(y',b)\in F'\times_f B$
then 
$$|x-y|_F=|x'-y'|_F
\ \ \ \Rightarrow\ \ \ 
|(x,a)-(y,b)| _{F\times_f B} = |(x',a)-(y',b)| _{F\times_f B}$$
If I remember right, this statement is due to S. Alexander and R. Bishop.

If you apply this to parabolic cone, you get a nice formula for distances,
which depent only on $|x-y|_F$ and two real values $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @Anton Petrunin:Nice formula.But I don't know how to get the formula.BGp(Alex 1) gives the elliptic cone formula,but no parabolic cone.